# Printing double digit numbers in LC-3

Tags: loops, assembly, addition, lc3, lc3-trap

Been learning about LC-3 lately and was wondering how do I go about printing a number that's bigger then 9? In this program I made it asks for width and length and multiplies the two to get the area of the shape. My problem is any output bigger then 9 it starts printing a letter or a number not close to what I wanted. How should I go about doing this? my code:

```
.ORIG x3000

; Reset Registers
AND R0, R0, #0
AND R1, R1, #0
AND R2, R2, #0
AND R3, R3, #0
AND R4, R4, #0
AND R5, R5, #0
AND R6, R6, #0
AND R7, R7, #0

LEA R0, numberone
PUTS
GETC
OUT
LD R3, HEXN30 
ADD R0, R0, R3
ADD R1, R0, #0


LEA R0, numbertwo
PUTS
GETC
OUT
ADD R0, R0, R3
ADD R6, R0, #0
LOOP
      ADD R2, R2, R1
      ADD R6, R6, #-1
BRp LOOP

LEA R0, MESG 
PUTS
ADD R0, R2, x0

LD R2, NEG_TEN  
ADD R2, R2, R0  
BRn JUMP    
AND R4, R4, #0  
ADD R4, R4, R2  
LD R0, ASCII_1 
OUT    
AND R0, R0, #0  
ADD R0, R0, R4  

JUMP

LD R3, HEX30 ;add 30 to integer to get integer character
ADD R0, R0, R3
OUT 

HALT ;{TRAP 25}


numberone  .stringz "\nPlease enter the length: "
numbertwo  .stringz "\nPlease enter the width: "
MESG .STRINGZ  "\n\nThe Area of the Rectangle is: "
HEXN30 .FILL xFFD0 ; -30 HEX
HEX30 .FILL x0030 ; 30 HEX
NEG_TEN .FILL #-10
ASCII_1 .FILL x0031 ; ASCII char '1'
.END
```

Example Output:

```
Please enter the length: 4
Please enter the width: 5
The area of the object is: 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will always print `1`:

```
LD R0, ASCII_1 
OUT
```

There's no chance for it to print a `2` like you'd want from 4 times 5.

---

The next character prints as `:` because you have `10` in `R4`, as you haven't subtracted `10` enough times in the division by repetitive subtraction.  You've only subtracted `10` once and `20` needs to have `10` subtracted twice (to get `0` as the remainder).

---

You should be able to see the first problem by simply reading the code there.  How could loading an ascii `1` and printing it do anything other than print a `1`?  So there is some missing code there.

The latter problem is a form of off-by-one error (looping one to few iterations), which is something you should be looking for during single-step debugging.  You want your division by repetitive subtraction to leave you with a remainder between 0 and 9 — definitely not 10!

Boundary conditions are very error prone.  Using `<` when it should be `<=` (or vice vesa), for example, can result in an off by one error.  What we do is try to use idioms to avoid these problems (like `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`), but when an idiom isn't applicable, then you want to be suspicious of and test those boundary conditions: at the boundary, at one less, at one more.

Comment: I understood what you meant by the second part and looped it again to produce the 0. My problem is trying to fix the LD R0, ASCII_1 
OUT line. I get a " Instruction references undefined label 'ASCII_2' when i try to change it from 1 to 2. Also another error "Instruction references non-addressable memory location -1"

Comment: Sorry again I actually got it now! thanks you solved my question. Made me think abit